# MS SQL - The multi-part identifier "Group.GroupId" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

In order to create a little workaround to the issue, that I can't create a certificate / symmetric key in a stored procedure, I inserted the commands as text to the code, which should then be executed correctly. Now I seem to have it all in place to run correctly, except for this last error, that the editor is giving me. I don't really understand, what he's trying to tell me...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_Group]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@GroupName varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
declare @SQL varchar(max)
declare @Key varchar(max)

-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
begin tran
insert into dbo.[Group]([GroupName], [KeyAttribute]) values(@GroupName, '')

select @SQL = 'IF NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM sys.certificates WHERE name = ''Cert_'+ [Group].GroupId + ''')
CREATE CERTIFICATE ''Cert_'' +[Group].GroupId ''  
WITH SUBJECT = ''I like kittens.'';'

execute (@SQL);
print @SQL

select @Key = 'IF NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM sys.symmetric_keys WHERE name = ''Key_'+[Group].GroupId+''') 
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY Key_'+[Group].GroupId+'
WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256
ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Cert_'+[Group].GroupId+';'

execute (@Key)
print @Key

commit

END
```

Any ideas are more than welcome!

**UPDATE**

I implemented the *Scope Identity* statement, as [devio](/questions/tagged/devio) suggested, whereas I added a little bit of casting to it, to make it compatible. It's not quite there yet though. The query executes fine now, but if I run the procedure it doesn't accept my boxed varchar statements.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_Group]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @GroupName varchar(50)
    AS
BEGIN
    declare @SQL varchar(max)
    declare @Key varchar(max)
    declare @LastInsertId int

    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    begin tran
    insert into dbo.[Group] ([GroupName], [KeyAttribute] ,[KeyName], [CertName]) values(@GroupName, '', '', '');
    set @LastInsertId =  SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    update [dbo].[Group]
    set [KeyName] = 'Key_' + (CAST (@LastInsertId AS varchar(max)))  
    where [GroupId] = @LastInsertId;

    update dbo.[Group] 
    set [CertName] = 'Cert_' + (CAST (@LastInsertId AS varchar(max)))  
    where [GroupId] = @LastInsertId;

select @SQL = 'IF NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM sys.certificates WHERE name = ''Cert_' +(CAST (@LastInsertId AS varchar(max)))+''')
    CREATE CERTIFICATE ''Cert_'' +(CAST (@LastInsertId AS varchar(max)))''  
    WITH SUBJECT = ''I like kittens.'';'

execute (@SQL)
print @SQL

select @Key = 'IF NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM sys.symmetric_keys WHERE name = ''Key_'+(CAST (@LastInsertId AS varchar(max)))+''') 
    CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY Key_'+(CAST (@LastInsertId AS varchar(max)))+'
    WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256
    ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Cert_'+(CAST (@LastInsertId AS varchar(max)))+';'

execute (@Key)
print @Key

    commit

END
```

Comment: Your code looks to be a mix-match of dynamic and non-dynamic sql and the syntax is completely broken because of it. You cannot do what you're trying to do so I would suggest starting over and taking it a single step at the time.

Comment: I bet and I would if I had the time.. I just need to get it running right now.. I can still copy the running project and push it back into dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `[Group].GroupId` you seem to try to access the primary key value of the newly created record. But in fact, the expression '[Group].GroupId' does not refer to anything.

In SQL Server, this is achieved using [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql)

```
DECLARE @GroupID INT
INSERT ...
SELECT @GroupID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: 'Twas a good tip! Just for completion: The return value of SCOPE_IDENTITY() is int, naturally. The constant 'Cert_' and 'Key_' aren't. So in order to make it work correctly I added CAST to the statement. (see above)